# Resample or normalize trajectory data so points are evenly spaced

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I have a DataFrame which contains X & Y data for many trajectories (not GPS data).

I am trying to figure out how to resample/time-normalize them so the distance between points is evenly spaced.

As they are right now, there are regions of the trajectories with higher density of points.

In the below scatterplots, I show one of the overall trajectories, and then a zoomed in portion of the trajectory to show how the density of points changes (i.e, the spacing between points is irregular).

[image: overall trajectory]

[image: zoomed in portion with irregular spacing between points]

My dataframes look like this:

```
     (0, 1, 1)_mean_X  (0, 1, 1)_mean_Z  ...  (2, 2, 3)_mean_X  (2, 2, 3)_mean_Z
0          -15.856713          5.002617  ...        -15.874083         -5.000582
1          -15.831320          5.003529  ...        -15.848551         -5.000925
2          -15.805927          5.004441  ...        -15.823020         -5.001268
3          -15.780534          5.005353  ...        -15.797489         -5.001611
4          -15.755141          5.006265  ...        -15.771958         -5.001955
..                ...               ...  ...               ...               ...
995         15.547392         11.280298  ...         15.257689        -12.455845
996         15.548967         11.278968  ...         15.258225        -12.457202
997         15.550542         11.277638  ...         15.258761        -12.458560
998         15.552116         11.276309  ...         15.259296        -12.459917
999         15.553691         11.274979  ...         15.259832        -12.461275
```

Comment: Hi, can you provide a sample of your data?

Comment: you can resample with ... erm [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html)

Comment: @Stef not if you don't have a datetime-like index

Comment: @anon01 correct, but OP wrote he wants to *time-normalize* so I figured the x-values would be some kind of time information (timestamps for instance), but yes - your answer if excellent for the given case (+1)

Comment: The sample doesn't look right. Why you said that you have X and Y coordinates, but there are some columns named Z in the data, and why are there more than two columns?

Comment: Z is equal to Y in this dataset. The dataset contains many different trajectories. Only one is plotted as an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas has an interp function, but for processing like this I would prefer numpy/scipy.  The vectorized functions are often faster than pandas.  Example:

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

x = np.logspace(0,2,300)
y = x**2
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([x, y]).T, columns=list("xy"))

# define interpolation function:
f = interp1d(x, y)

# create new df with desired x vals, generate y with interp function:
x_new = np.linspace(x.min(),x.max(),1000)
y_new = f(x_new)
df_new = pd.DataFrame(np.array([x_new, y_new]).T, columns=["x_new", "y_new"])
```

Note this will fail if `x_new` is outside the original domain - this makes sense as it's just linear interpolation.

Comment: Thanks but doesnt seem to be working on my end. The new x and y values are originally ranging from -20 to + 20 but after doing this the values go into the millions. Also, the x & y data are both positional/spatial, so the index is the only measure of 'time'.

Comment: I see that when I run your code on my data

Comment: thanks, im trying to figure out how to get it working with my data and will accept & upvote as soon as I do. It seems like I need to run this code on the X and Y positions separately, but when I tried to do that it didnt return evenly spaced points.

Comment: From a discussion with the op https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66221994/interpolation-to-evenly-space-trajectory-data-for-different-curves#comment117079104_66221994 it appears that you misunderstood the question... The `x` column is not the time data, it's a coordinate value.